# MatFormField Containing Textarea Height 100%

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I am using Angular Flex Layout to design my components. Unfortunately I am stuck with one simple task. My `textarea` must occupy 100% of the height of the component. I can see that the height is 100% on the `mat-form-field` but the wrapper isn't. Below is my code:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxFlex="1 0 auto">

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput formControlName="name" required>
        </textarea>
        <mat-error>Name is required!</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

Comment: include the attribute fxFlexFill in the  div element  ...  fxLayoutAlign=”start stretch” fxLayout=”row”